# Add a condition to query list of a function in Python

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have an eCommerce website with Django, I want to put a condition with if statement to my payment function that only if product sold status is false proceed to payment and if not output a message to user.
I cannot workout a way to approach this. any help would be appreciated

here is my payment function :

```
def acc_go_to_gateway_view(request):
    cart_items = AccountCart.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    print (cart_items)
    total_price = 0
    if cart_items:
        for item in cart_items:
            total_price += (item.product.price) * item.quantity

    amount = total_price    

    user_mobile_number = ''

    factory = bankfactories.BankFactory()
    try:
        bank = factory.auto_create()
        bank.set_request(request)
        bank.set_amount(amount)

        bank.set_client_callback_url('/acc-callback-gateway')
        bank.set_mobile_number(user_mobile_number)
    
      
        bank_record = bank.ready()
        
        return bank.redirect_gateway()
    except AZBankGatewaysException as e:
        logging.critical(e)
        raise e
```

and this is my product model sold status is like this  :

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    sold = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and the Cart model that the bank function conntects to is :

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(AccountProduct, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

since the payment function works with my cart model , and in my cart model the product model connects via a foreign key i couldnt use filter() modifier and i cant workout how to do this

Comment: So if the cart contains *any* such product? Is `AccountProduct` the same as `Product`?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem  , user cannot add the sold product to their cart, this is for users that had the product in their cart already and proceed to pay after someone has already bought the product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you reduce the number of queries quite effectively by calculating the total price, and whether there is an item that is sold out by aggregating at the database side.

Indeed:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

removed, __ = AccountCart.objects.filter(
    user=request.user, product__sold=True
).delete()
if removed:
    return redirect('name-of-some-view')
total_price = AccountCart.objects.filter(user=request.user).aggregate(
    total_price=Sum(F('quantity') * F('product__price'))
)['total_price']
```

This will *only* remove the `Product`s from the carts that are no longer sold, so the user can for example check the cart with products still available, and since the prices are calculate at the database side, we only need one query to do that.

---

> **Note**: While Django's [**`redirect(…)`** function <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) *does* accept paths, the main idea is to use the *name* of a view (optionally with parameters), and let Django determine the path. This also makes it more robust against changes of paths.

Comment: Very interesting and effective approach.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this !
I defined a cart_items which filters products in users cart,
then i used a for loop to go through all products in the cart and used an if statement to check if each product has status sold and if it does i redirect user to cart and delete their cart

```
    cart_items = AccountCart.objects.filter(user=request.user,)
        current_user = request.user
        for item in cart_items:
            if item.product.sold == True:
                AccountCart.objects.filter(user=current_user).delete()
                return redirect('/accountshop/cart')
```